# Cannot connect socket.io client to server through some specific mobile network

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, socket.io, client

We have a node.js server with socket.io that handles real time stuff. We also have socket.io clients in android which interact with the server through [Gottox/socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client).

The problem is that we arent being able to comunicate clients with server through some specific mobile network. Comunication is stablished without any problem through wifi.

We have checked our server logs and we see that only the handshake part appears when some of the clients tries to connect to the server via this specific mobile network and nothing more happens.

```
debug - client authorized
info - handshake authorized oFpfNtLLvVzCnpKgyxpe
```

On the client side, no event is triggered after the socket creation (onConnect or onError) so there is no way to know what happened from the client side.

This problem only happens if we have websockets enabled, we have tried disabling websockets which causes clients to connect via xhr-polling, but we have seen that the performance is terrible if we use this setup.

We have tried changing the server ports (80, 8080, 443) with any luck.

We have also tested what is going on with websockets opening http://websocketstest.com/ through this mobile network but everything seems to be ok (No errors).

What could be the cause of this problem? we appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: You said you tried with port 443 but did you try to use SSL ?

Comment: Nope, we havent tried using SSL, we do not want SSL for now

Comment: In my opinion, secure websockets through ssl is best way to make it work everywhere.